# What is VB.NET Version of this Code?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
  BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  {
    textBox1.Text = args.Fax.Port.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString();
  }));
}
```

Comment: In the future, it helps to note what error message was received from the compiler ;)

Comment: Just pasting the converted VB.Net code (from developerfusion.com) into my app... I end up with 14 errors of the flavor:

Declaration expected. / Satement cannot appear outside of a method. / 'End Try' must be preceded by a matching 'Try' / 'End Sub' must be preceded by a matching 'Sub' / 
'If' must end with a matching 'End If' / Expression expected / 'End Sub' expected / End of statement expected

Comment: Jon, thanks for the tag edit.  So many choices...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx)

```
Delegate Sub MyDelegate(myControl As Label, myArg2 As String)

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim myArray(1) As Object

   myArray(0) = New Label()
   myArray(1) = "Enter a Value"
   myTextBox.BeginInvoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf DelegateMethod), myArray)
End Sub 

Public Sub DelegateMethod(myControl As Label, myCaption As String)
   myControl.Location = New Point(16, 16)
   myControl.Size = New Size(80, 25)
   myControl.Text = myCaption
   Me.Controls.Add(myControl)
End Sub
```

So

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
  BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  {
    textBox1.Text = args.Fax.Port.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString();
  }));
}

Delegate Sub MyDelegate(faxPort As String, faxStatus As String)

If InvokeRequired Then
    Dim aArray(1) as Object
    aArray(0) = args.Fax.Port.ToString()
    aArray(1) = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString();
    BeginInvoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf MySub), aArray)
End If

Sub MySub( faxPort as String, faxStatus as String)
    textBox1.Text = faxPort
    textBox2.Text = faxStatus
End Sub
```

I think

Answer (score 5):

Courtesy of [developerfusion.com](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/):

```
If InvokeRequired Then
    BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(Function() Do
        textBox1.Text = args.Fax.Port.ToString()
        textBox2.Text = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString()
    End Function))
End If
```

Comment: @beaudetious: there might be some problem with other parts of your code!

Comment: My code is working fine in the c# app I wrote.  Now I'm trying to write a VB.Net version for a client and this one part is holding me up.

Comment: A cursory examination of the code shows it to be a 1:1 correlation. Also, given that C# and VB.NET are _nearly_ 1:1 there's not much way for it to be wrong. ~ what's the compiler error?

Comment: @drachenstern: Until 2010, VB.Net does not support this.

Comment: Yes I just saw your comment. Also, the comment by Darin Dimitrov doesn't include a reference to args per your comment.

Answer (score 4):

VB.NET 9 and previous does not support multi line anonymous functions. You need to write a separate function:

```
If InvokeRequired Then
    BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf MySub))
End If
```

where MySub:

```
Sub MySub()
    textBox1.Text = args.Fax.Port.ToString()
    textBox2.Text = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString()    
End Sub
```

---

UPDATE:

To clarify about the `args` parameter there's an overload of [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx) that could be used and in this case the [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) delegate is no longer suitable. [Action(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) would work:

```
If InvokeRequired Then
    BeginInvoke(New Action(Of SomeType)(AddressOf MySub), args)
End If
```

and:

```
Sub MySub(ByVal args as SomeType)
    textBox1.Text = args.Fax.Port.ToString()
    textBox2.Text = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString()    
End Sub
```

After all it's simple things like this that make C# developers happy :-) (please don't take it wrong, I have nothing against VB.NET)

Comment: `args` is probably a parameter to the original method.

Comment: Great suggestion, but how do I pass the arguments to MySub from MethodInvoker?

Answer (score 3):

Until Visual Studio 2010, VB.Net does not support multi-statement anonymous functions.

You need to move the anonymous method into a separate method that takes `args` as a parameter, then call `Invoke` on it.

Comment: Really? Thanks for the info. I was not aware of that one-line limitation with VB.NET <10

Answer (score 1):

Since the comments do not allow formatting, I'm going to post my working solution here.  Thanks to all who chimed in - Darin, SLaks, drachenstern, Jay.

```
Private Sub myControl_FaxStatus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As DataTech.FaxManNet.FaxEventArgs)
  frmModemStatus.UpdateStatus(args.Fax)

  If InvokeRequired Then
    Dim aArray(1) As Object
    aArray(0) = args.Fax.Port.ToString()
    aArray(1) = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString()
    BeginInvoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf UpdateStatusDisplay), aArray)
  End If

  Try
    TextBox1.Text = args.Fax.Port.ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = args.Fax.FaxStatus.ToString()
  Catch ex As Exception
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ex = " & ex.ToString())
  End Try

End Sub

Delegate Sub MyDelegate(ByVal faxPort As String, ByVal faxStatus As String)

Private Sub UpdateStatusDisplay(ByVal faxPort As String, ByVal faxStatus As String)
  TextBox1.Text = faxPort
  TextBox2.Text = faxStatus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need similar stuff in the feature just install the following component to your visual studio. 
After that you can easly convert from c# to vb.net or vb.net to c#.
VS2010 Support is already included.
http://codeconvert.codeplex.com/